# Setting mask dynamically from code primeng Angular 5

Tags: angular, primeng

Wanting to reuse the input field but change the mask with respect to the values else where on the form (for example, selected value from p-dropdown select box, if selected value is "Mobile" then mask for mobile phone applied, if it is e-mail then email mask applied). I am trying to achive this with the code belove but it is not working.

```
<p-inputMask formControlName="communicationType" mask="{{communicationTypeMask}}"></p-inputMask>
```

Any ideas if this is possible or an event to call to get it to recognize the mask change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onChange` event from `p-dropdown` to update the mask of `p-inputMask`.

```
<p-dropdown [options]="communications" [(ngModel)]="communication" (onChange)="changeMask()"></p-dropdown>
```

And here is the TS code :

```
   changeMask() {
     if(this.communication==="mobile") {
       this.communicationTypeMask = "99 99 99 99 99";
     } else if(this.communication==="mail") {
       this.communicationTypeMask = "**********@*****.**";
     } else {
       this.communicationTypeMask = "";
     }
   }
```

(don't care about masks I've written, they're wrong but it's not the point)

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/u5QJlKtc1T9GZL8pdffR?p=preview)

Comment: yes this is solving my problem. but I want to consult with you about one more thing. Mask constrains user such as, in your mail mask, after dot he can enter only two digit.However after dots it could be .com, .net etc. At this point is it possible to use mask with regexp ?